# How can I pass a collection of objects to the view in my MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following action method that returns a collection of AdminDetail instances:

```
   public ActionResult DetailData()
    {
        var vm = _reference.Detail().ToList();
        return PartialView("~/Areas/Administration/Views/References/_DetailData.cshtml", vm);
    }
```

Here's my AdminDetail class:

```
namespace Storage.Models
{
    public class AdminDetail
    {
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
        public string RowKey { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public string Order { get; set; }
        public int Row { get; set; }
    }
```

In my razor view what should I put for the model? If I just put the following then it is only for one instance:

```
@model Storage.Models.AdminDetail

    @foreach (var detail in Model.AdminDetails)
    {
```

How can I pass a collection of AdminDetails using my model to the view? I am not sure if viewdata is an option but I would rather not use that as I heard it's not really a good choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a collection of `AdminDetail` as your view model type so that you can loop through the elements:

```
@model IEnumerable<Storage.Models.AdminDetail>
@foreach (var detail in Model)
{
    <div>@detail.Title</div>
    ...
}
```

or using a display template you can avoid the loop:

```
@model IEnumerable<Storage.Models.AdminDetail>
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

and inside the corresponding display template which will automatically be rendered for each element of the collection (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/AdminDetail.cshtml`):

```
@model Storage.Models.AdminDetail
<div>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Title)</div>
...
```

Comment: +1 given the reasonable assumption that `.ToList()` in this case returns and `IEnum<>`

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Just one question. When I try the way you suggest I don't get intellitype on @detail.  Is that to be expected?

Comment: @Melissa, no, it's not expected. Make sure that the assembly containing the AdminDetail class is referenced and that the namespace that you have specified is correct. You must get Intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a list as your model - a model in MVC3 can be anything you want. Just set List as the model of the view.

Alternatively, use the ViewBag (although I would not recommend to abuse it as you loose IntelliSense). ViewBag is like a dynamically typed dictionary which is available from both the View and the Controller.
Here's an example:

Controller:

```
ViewBag.Color = "Blue";
```

View:

```
<h1> The color is <%: ViewBag.Color %> </h1>
```

Comment: But if I did that then how would I specify it on the first line? @model Storage.Models.IEnum<AdminDetail> is okay?

Comment: The other reply got it right: 
@model IEnumerable<Storage.Models.AdminDetail> (or you can say List instead but for Dependency Inversion reasons some people don't like it)